# How To Make Photoshop CS6 Tilt-Shift Guidelines Reappear?

Tags: software, photoshop, tilt-shift

In Photoshop, the guidelines for the new blur effects (the lines that indicate which parts of the photo are being blurred and that can be moved, tilted, etc) completely disappeared. I'm assuming I pressed something to make that happen, but can't seem to find what it was to make them re-appear.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I had the same problem, and nove of these solutions worked. What did work? Command+H. If you have the selections hidden, the guides for tilt-shift are hidden, too...

Answer (score 2):

First thing to check is if you have View > Extras unchecked. That hides guides and gridlines.  Ctrl+H (Cmd+H on a Mac) is a shortcut.

If it's not that, then check the Blur Tools panel.

[image]

If you click on the arrow next to tilt shift to expand the panel, the grid lines will reappear.  When you collapse that panel, it also hides the gridlines.

[image]

If that doesn't work, try Ctrl-0 to display the entire image (or just zoom out) and see if the gridlines are just way outside the boundary of your image.  If so, you can click and drag them back in.

Answer (score 1):

go to view -> show -> and check edit pins while using the filter